# is this possible to only show list view holding for some specific child value of real time Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created this database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBnFO.png) and want to show the list specifically for the child availability: "Available" item.  I have nearly reached to the goal by this code

```
public class Homeuser extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
ListView lv;

FirebaseListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homeuser);

    final Vibrator vibeuser = (Vibrator) Homeuser.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("food");
    lv = findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    FirebaseListOptions<food> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<food>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.list_items).setLifecycleOwner(Homeuser.this)
            .setQuery(query,food.class).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options)
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
            TextView itemname, itemprice, avail;

            itemname = v.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
            itemprice = v.findViewById(R.id.itemprice);
            avail = v.findViewById(R.id.avail);

            food itemFood = (food) model;

            if(itemFood.getAvailability().toString().equals("Available")){
            itemname.setText(itemFood.getFooditemname().toString());
            itemprice.setText(itemFood.getFooditemprice().toString());
            avail.setText(itemFood.getAvailability().toString());}
        }

    };}}
```

But faces a problem like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x5th.png) how to get rid of this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the element that you want to get rid?

Comment: @AlexMamo The List View contains empty rows( there status is "Not Available") which I don't want to show in this activity.

Comment: I understandn now, I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter Firebase database records, you should use a query along with a `whereEqual()` call and **not** an if statement inside your `populateView()` method. So to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("food");
```

to

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("food")
    .orderByChild("availability")
    .equalTo("Available");
```

And remove the if statement.